# What is the need for function parameters? Many possible inputs

Tags: plotting, functions, variable-definitions

If I have many possible variables related to one another, why do I need to define my function with parameters for plotting? For example, if I have an equation like:

```
output_value := a * b * c * d / ( e * f * g * h );
```

Assuming that all values are defined and have some default value, why can't I just do this to plot:

```
Plot[ output_value, { b, 0, 100 } ];
```

The annoying thing is having to do this:

```
output_value[aparam_, bparam_, cparam_, dparam_, eparam_, fparam_, gparam_, hparam_] := aparam * bparam * cparam * dparam / ( eparam * fparam * gparam * hparam );
```

and then:

```
With[ {aparam=a,cparam=c,dparam=d,eparam=e,fparam=f,gparam=g}, Plot[ output_value, { bparam, 0, 100 } ];
```

Comment: BTW, you can ease your pain by writing `With[{a = a, c = c, ...}, ...]` . See the third example under `With` in the Documentation Center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to define a function to plot it. You can certainly do

```
a=1;
f:=a+x;
Plot[f,{x,0,10}]
```

and the output is the graph you expected. Defining the function as above has many drawbacks:

1) You cannot evaluate it without making an explicit replacement. For example, `f(2)` becomes

```
f/.x->2
```

I would generalize this point and say that defining $f(x)$ with a `f[x_]` gives convenience down the road.

2) You have to be careful not to use the variable that you are "reserving" for the independent variable:

```
<<lots of code>> x=3; <<lots of code>> f/.x->2
```

The last evaluation of `f/.x->2` will not necessarily give you the $f(2)$ that you might have expected. I would generalize this point and say that defining $f(x)$ with a `f[x_]` makes it more difficult to shoot oneself in the foot.

Comment: I see, so basically you are saying that using function parameters is optional. Thats good.

Comment: @TylerDurden One of the places where parameter lists are almost a necessity is in `Manipulate`, where sliders won't update a parameter in a function if it isn't explicitly visible to Manipulate.